# Снять jQuery.live

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем доброго времени суток. Допустим, событие повешено так: **`$('.a, .b').live(...)`**. В какой-то момент событие надо отвязать от **.b**. Есть вариант функцию в live передавать по имени, когда надо - делать die() для выборки и перепривязывать событие к **.a**. А есть ли красивое решение, не зависящее от первоначальной выборки? К примеру, отвязать событие от **span** из **`.a, .b`**.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

ИМХО если возникает такая необходимость - значит вы думаете не в том направлении, если вам не нужны спаны - так и **укажите это в выборке**, в любом случае, даже если такое решение есть вы понимаете насколько это ресурсоемкая операция?

И вообще ИМХО обработчики событий должны изменятся только для динамических элементов (это делает за нас live). Если они от чего либо зависят - **укажите это в коде**. В любом случае, при таком подходе, многим пользователям старых IE ооочень не понравиться ваша идея, под IE7- даже выборка по className довольно ресурсоемкая операция, а тут такое...

Comment: Почему же не в том? Чисто гипотетически может создаться такая ситуация, когда надо отвязать onclick с кнопки OK в модальных окнах, если снят определенный флажок. При том, что модуль окон писали не вы, код обфусцирован, а автора уже давно и нет.  
По поводу IE - что, теперь совсем нельзя делать выборки по классам, из-за одного только факта существования этого динозавра? Часто возникает такая ситуация, когда проще делать выборку по классу (хотя и с уточнением).  
Да и вообще, мне IE напоминает Волгу 90х годов на автостраде. Некогда шикарное авто, еле тянущее на современных скоростях.

Comment: Что касается меня я вообще не веду разработку под IE меньше 9ой версии, чего и вам желаю.

По поводу код обсуфицирован - тогда да (увы никак по другому), а вот что касается флажка - это надо, по хорешему, опять так - описывать в обработчике события, что-то вида

      if(canDoThat) {
          // do...
      }

По вашему вопросу гуглил и сделал вывод что, кроме как снести все и сразу через die() - выхода нет. Если плевать на IE - делайте так, в нормальных браузерах это отработает хорошо, ну а в IE - отработает как-то. Главное что отработает таки :D Главное чтобы процесс не надо было снимать :